# fopen using Xcode in mac

Tags: c, xcode, macos, fopen

I used like this:

```
FILE *employees=fopen("employees.txt", "a");
if (!employees)
    return 0;
```

and the file was created, then I wrote to it and afterwards I read from it successfully.
Now, I tried to find it in finder on my mac and I couldn't find it.
can you help me and tell me where it was created?

Comment: It should be located in the same directory that you executed the program from.

Comment: Right-click your executable in the Products folder in the left sidebar, and select "Show in Finder".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is in the current working directory of the process that created it. If you ran this from Xcode, that directory will be the built products directory for your project. It will look something like

```
/Users/you/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/YourProject-dpiipcwhytjlsgejubbdjiveruiy/Build/Products/Debug
```

The easiest way to find this directory is to open your project, look in the file list for the Products group, and right-click the file that represents your built app and select Show in Finder.